# TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, typeerror

What's wrong here?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
ts = pd.Series(randint(0, 500, len(rng)), index=rng)
```

Gives:
TypeError: randint() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

System:
Python 2.7.5+
Pandas 0.12.0-2ubuntu1

Comment: Where is the function `randint` coming from? Because it is a numpy fucntion, but when you import `numpy as np`, this should be `np.random.randint()`, and that is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you randint comes from the standard library (random.randint)

Here are two ways to correct your code

1. modify `randint` to `np.random.randint`
2. add `from numpy.random import randint`

Comment: Lookout, there should be a space: from numpy.random import randint